# Backbone.js: Read a json file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am very new to backbone.js and I am trying to read a json file with backbone js. Here is my code.

```
var SaveReportView= Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "textarea",
el: $('#build'), // el attaches to existing element
events: {
    'click #saveReport': 'saveReportHandler'
},

initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},


render: function(){
    $(this.el).append("<button id='saveReport' class='btn btn-info'>Save</button>");

},

saveReportHandler: function(){    
    console.log($("#target").html()); 
    console.log($("#table-0").html()); 

    file = fopen(getScriptPath("data.json"), 0);
    file_length = flength(file);
    content = fread(file, file_length);
    console.log(content);


},

});

var reportView= new SaveReportView();
```

This gives following error on console log.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fopen is not defined
```

Anyone has any idea what's wrong with my code ?

Thank You

Comment: Where is your `data.json` file ?

Comment: @throrin, thanks for being first one putting a comment. My data.json file is in D drive. My project source also in there.

Comment: What is `fopen`..? the error clearly states it's not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. you are writing PHP in a JavaScript file. I think you need to learn some basics on web development :)

To request a json file in JS on the client you use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX). Backbone wraps this data and request in a model or a collection of models.

You would have a model which does a [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) for the data and populates the model with attributes. Often the data you want to apply to the model is nested and you would override [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to get to the needed object but since you didn't show what is in the json file the basics of it is:

```
var ReportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: 'data.json'
});

var reportModel = new ReportModel();

reportModel.fetch().done(function() {
    console.log('successful');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('failed');
});
```

A typical approach would be to pass the instantiated model via the `model` option when instantiating the view. The view then does the fetch and/or waits for the fetch to complete on the model - `this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.onFetchSuccess);`. If you are lost in all this I recommend you learn some JS and Backbone basics from a tutorial first!